# Reading multiple lines user input in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi I have a program where if the user inputs a filename I read form the file else I will prompt them for input.

Currently I am doing:

```
    input=$(cat)
    echo $input>stdinput.txt
    file=stdinput.txt
```

The problem with this is it doesn't read the newline characters in input, for example if I input

```
s,5,8
kyle,5,34,2 
j,2
```

output

```
s,5,8 k,5,34,2 j,2
```

The intended output to be stored in a file is

```
s,5,8
kyle,5,34,2 
j,2
```

I need to know how to include the newline character while reading.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` will suppress the newlines. You don't need the additional `$input` variable as you can directly redirect `cat`'s output to the file:

```
file=stdinput.txt
cat > "$file"
```

Also it makes more sense for me to define `$file` before the `cat`. Have changed this.

---

If you need the user input in both the file and `$input` then `tee` would suffice. If you pipe the output of `cat` (user input) to `tee` the input will be written to both the file and `$input`:

```
file=stdinput.txt
input=$(cat | tee "$file")
```

Comment: I tried but when I cat the file i.e. cat $file it doesn't show anything.

Comment: `cat $file` works for me (means content is in the file).. But with my previous solution `$input` was empty. Have changed this and use `tee` now

Answer (score 2):

Try quoting the variable while echoing it:

```
input=$(cat)
echo "$input">stdinput.txt
file=stdinput.txt
```

Example:

```
$ input=$(cat)
s,5,8
kyle,5,34,2 
j,2
$ echo "$input">stdinput.txt
$ cat stdinput.txt 
s,5,8
kyle,5,34,2 
j,2
$
```

while indeed, not quoting the variable leads to the situation you describe

```
$ echo $input>stdinput.txt
$ cat stdinput.txt 
s,5,8 kyle,5,34,2 j,2
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use such syntax:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > new_file << EOF
This will be line one
This will be line two
This will be line three
   This will be line four indented
Notice the absence of spaces on the next line
EOF
```

Here `cat` reads text until it encounters delimeter (`EOF` in our case). Delimeter string may be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Would `printf` help?

```
printf "$input">stdinput.txt
```